# Relation of length of small circle with that of a great circle

Tags: positional-astronomy, spherical-astronomy

> This is not the best place to ask such doubts, so please recommend where I can. I currently don't have the facility to ask a teacher specialized for astronomy.

So I just got reading- "Astronomy: Principles and Practice, Fourth Edition by A. Roy and D. Clarke" and I couldn't understand some lines (a possible derivation for some geometrical formula, which I have no clue about)

It stated the following:-

""The length of a small circle arc, such as $FG$ is related simply to the length of an arc of the great circle whose plane is parallel to that of the small circle In figure 7.1, let $r$ be the radius of the small circle $EFGHE$. Then
$$FG = r × ∠FKG$$.

Also
$$BC= R×∠BOC$$.

Both $OB$ and $KF$ lie on plane $PFBQ$; $KF$ also lies on plane $EFGH$ while $OB$ lies on plane $ABCD$. Therefore, $KF$ must be parallel to $OB$, since plane $EFGH$ is parallel to plane $ABCD$. Similarly, $KG$ is parallel to $OC$ Then
$$∠FKG = ∠BOC$$.
Hence,
$$FG = BC × r/R$$.

In the plane triangle $KOF$, right-angled at $K$, $KF=r$; $OF = R$. Hence,
$$FG = BC × \sin KOF$$.
But $∠POB = 90^\circ$ so that we may write alternatively
$$FG = BC\cos FB$$.
If the radius of the sphere is unity,
$$PF = ∠POF = ∠KOF$$
and
$$FB = ∠FOB$$,
so that we have
$$FG = BC\sin PF$$
and
$$FG = BC\cos FB$$.""

Here is the figure 7.1 it was talking about:-
[image: figure 7.1]

I couldn't understand what it wanted to derive. Also how can $\sin PF$ and $\cos FB$ be possible? aren't $PF$ and $FB$ arcs? Could anyone please help, I will be grateful!

Comment: The author says *FB=∠FOB*, because for a unit sphere or circle (and angles measured in radians) the length of an arc is identical to the measure of angle subtending it. So _cos BF_ is _cos∠FOB_. As for what the author is trying to derive, he says it right at the top: it's to relate the length FG to BC. Which he does in the last two lines.

Comment: @ScienceSnake this addresses the issue, thanks, you can answer this question if you want to, instead

Comment: I finally got one of the possible reasons why- the author wanted to derive the formula for *departure*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the text you quoted confusing - obviously the reason for your question. In particular it wasn't clear whether arcs were measured as distance over the ground or radians/angles. HTH.[image]